# Does an airplane has to take off from beginning of the runway or it can take off from displaced threshold?

Tags: landing, takeoff, pilots

I mean, if the airports declared that there is a displaced threshold of runway ; and airplanes use this length for landing but how about for takeoff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Can the displaced threshold be used for takeoff?

The part of the runway in front of the displaced threshold **must not** be used for **landing** (it can be used from the other direction during roll-out), but it may be used for **takeoff**:

> 2. **Displaced Threshold.** A displaced threshold is a threshold located at a point on the runway other than the designated beginning of the runway. Displacement of a threshold reduces the length of runway available for landings. The portion of runway behind a displaced threshold is available for takeoffs in either direction and landings from the opposite direction.
>
> [image: Displaced Threshold Markings]

<sup>([FAA AIM Chapter 2 - Section 3 - Airport Marking Aids and Signs](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html))</sup>

This also follows the ICAO definitions in Annex 14, Volume 1, Attachment A, Volume 1, 3. Calculation of declared distances:

> - The declared distances to be calculated for each runway direction comprise: the take-off run available (TORA), take-off distance available (TODA), accelerate-stop distance available (ASDA), and landing distance available (LDA).
> - Where a runway has a displaced threshold, then the LDA will be reduced by the distance the threshold is displaced, as shown in Figure A-1 (D). A displaced threshold affects only the LDA for approaches made to that threshold; all declared distances for operations in the reciprocal direction are unaffected.
>
> [image: Declared Distances]

<sup>([Landing Distances on SKYbrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Landing_Distances))</sup>

Note that the TODA (TakeOff Distance Available) is unchanged in D, but the LDA (Landing Distance Available) is reduced.

### Does it have to be used for takeoff?

No, a takeoff can be performed starting from anywhere along the runway. This is typically called an **intersection takeoff**. Some airports even have taxiway signs displaying the remaining TORA at some taxiways:

[image: Intersection Takeoff]
<sup>([ICAO Standards - Airfield Information Signs](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2016/ACI/D2-03MarkingsSigns.pdf))</sup>

Such an intersection takeoff requires ATC clearance and of course that the aircraft takeoff performance calculations are done based on this intersection. See also [Are intersection takeoffs less common in the USA than in other countries?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75320/are-intersection-takeoffs-less-common-in-the-usa-than-in-other-countries)

Comment: Your answers were great but I think that I asked my question wrong; my question actually was: If there is a displaced threshold for a runway; can pilot start their rollout from the beginning of the runway(behind of the displaced threshold) or he/she has to take a clearance beginning of the displaced threshold and start to roll-out? thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: @VolkanEroğlu I see, I misunderstood that. I added another paragraph ;)

Comment: Is there also a "displaced threshold" for takeoffs?

Comment: @zymhan As in *an area that can only be used for landing, but not for takeoff*? Not that I know of.